# MS Access SQL "Like" and wildcard returning exact matches only

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables: CHART and GRANTs.

CHART contains fields CHART.ID and CHART.Account. The CHART.ID and CHART.Account combinations are unique per record.

The table GRANT contains GRANT.ID and GRANT.Accounts. GRANT.ID is unique per record, however the GRANT.Accounts field can be either a single account number, or several comma separated account numbers (ex: 1234, 5432, 9876, etc). Unfortunately I have no control over the structure of the report.

What I need is to match each CHART.ID to the applicable GRANT.ID via a partial match between CHART.Account and Grant.Accounts. For instance, if GRANT.ID Grant1 has Accounts 1234, 5432, 9876 I want to able to match CHART.Account 5432 as applicable to that GRANT.ID

```
SELECT GRANTS.ID, GRANTS.Accounts, CHART.ID, CHART.Account
FROM CHART, GRANTS
WHERE CHART.Account Like GRANTS.Accounts
```

So far, my SQL code returns only those records where CHART.Account matches GRANT.Accounts exactly, that is, only where there is only one Account in the GRANT.Account field. I've also tried various forms of wildcards with the LIKE to no success. I'm guessing my problem stems from a misunderstanding of how LIKE and wildcards work.

Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Wild card would need to be concatenated to the field value, and if you have lots of data this will get very slow, as the wildcard at the beginning of the searched term means that any indexes on it can't be used

```
SELECT GRANTS.ID, GRANTS.Accounts, CHART.ID, CHART.Account
FROM CHART, GRANTS
WHERE CHART.Account Like ("*" & GRANTS.Accounts & "*")
```

You could however use a query to make a temporary table of your distinct values, and then use a direct matched query. On a large dataset this would be much more efficient.

Just because your data arrives in a poor format, there's nothing to stop you manipulating it to a sensible format.

Comment: I actually tried that wildcard concatenation exactly as you have it, and I still only get the exact 1:1 matches. For whatever reason, the list values in GRANTS.Accounts are not matching with anything. I even had to confirm for myself that those values do in fact exist in CHART.Accounts

Our records are not extensive (~50,000 records per year if I remember correctly). So I'm more concerned with automation than efficiency. We have had some success with similar wildcard lookups in Excel, but I would really like to have a self contained access solution.

Comment: The comma separated values aren't in a multivalued field by any chance are they?

Comment: Try the wildcarding on the other side of the where e.g `"*" & Chart.account & "*"` I might be thinking it the wrong way around, and don't have any suitable sample data to play with.

Comment: Seems like we have similar troubleshooting though processes - I tried that as well. When you switch the wildcard like that, I get no results, not even the exact matches. I even tried the wildcard on both fields (grasping at straws at that point)

Comment: I can't try as I don't have suitable data to fiddle with this, but you could try using IN(GRANTS.Accounts) , not sure if it will evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can provide actual value examples of the two fields you are trying to match and they are not matching you can get more meaningful help.

At a guess, your query probably needs to be more like this:

```
SELECT GRANTS.ID, GRANTS.Accounts, CHART.ID, CHART.Account
FROM CHART
 INNER JOIN GRANTS ON CHART.Account Like ("*" & GRANTS.Accounts & "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

As `GRANTS.Accounts` (plural) holds the value list `CHART.Account` has to be the partial match

```sql
SELECT
    GRANTS.ID
  , GRANTS.Accounts
  , CHART.ID
  , CHART.Account
FROM
    CHART
    INNER JOIN
        GRANTS
    ON
        GRANTS.Accounts LIKE "*" & CHART.Account & "*"
```

If length of `CHART.Account` is not fixed, you have to include the delimiter in criteria or CHART.Account `1234` will match `12345` too (`,1234,`won't match `,12345,`)

```sql
SELECT
    GRANTS.ID
  , GRANTS.Accounts
  , CHART.ID
  , CHART.Account
FROM
    CHART
    INNER JOIN
        GRANTS
    ON
        "," & GRANTS.Accounts & "," LIKE "*," & CHART.Account & ",*"
```